# Comma to New Line

Tags: reactjs

In React, how can I turn `,` characters into new lines?

Suppose we have an array like this:

```js
const items = [
    {
        label: "Animals",
        value: "Puppies, Kittens, Bunnies"
    },
    // ...
];
```

And we display it like this:

```js
<div>
    {items.map(item => (
        <div style="left">
            {item.label}
        </div>
        <div style="right">
            {item.value}
        </div>
    ))};
</div>
```

How can I turn all `,` characters in the `value` keys of the array items into new lines?

---

Current Output:

```
Animals    Puppies, Kittens, Bunnies
```

Desired Output:

```
Animals    Puppies
           Kittens
           Bunnies
```

Comment: `{item.value.replace(', ', '\n')}` and ensure `div.right` is styled to preserve whitespace and linebreaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{item.value.split(", ").map((line, i) => <div key={i}>{line}</div>)}
```

is the simplest, if putting each item in a `div` is okay for you.

The other, more complex option is to add `<br>`s between each line, and wrap those in a `React.Fragment`:

```
function addBrs(items) {
  const children = [];
  items.forEach((item) => {
    children.push(item);
    children.push(<br />);
  });
  children.pop(); // Remove last extraneous BR
  return React.createElement(React.Fragment, {}, ...children);
}

// ...

{addBrs(item.value.split(", "))}}
```